# Magento 2 - Wysiwyg Images Not Showing in Custom Product Attributes Using Text Area

Tags: magento2

I have created a website that uses several custom product attributes which are text areas. The content pulls through just fine with the exception of the images which were placed in the text areas using the Wysiwyg Editor.

I have found a number of solutions online, non of which have had an effect and I am fairly sure the issue is likely to me not calling the attributes correctly.

The code I am using the the phtml file is:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();
if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
  $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
    <div>
        <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
        <div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php

$dimensions = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('dimensions')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$features_benefits = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('features_benefits')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$flooring_specification = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('flooring_specification')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$timber_grades = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('timber_grades')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$profiles_available = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('profiles_available')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$specification = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('specification')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

if (!empty($dimensions) || !empty($features_benefits) || !empty($flooring_specification) || !empty($timber_grades) || !empty($profiles_available) || !empty($specification)) {
    ?>
    <?php
    if (!empty($dimensions)) {
        ?>
        <h2>Dimensions</h2>
        <?php echo $dimensions; ?>
        <?php
    }
    if (!empty($features_benefits)) {
        ?>
        <h2>Features & Benefits</h2>
        <?php echo $features_benefits; ?>
        <?php
    }
    if (!empty($flooring_specification)) {
        ?>
        <h2>Specification</h2>
        <?php echo $flooring_specification; ?>
        <?php
    }
    if (!empty($timber_grades)) {
        ?>
        <h2>Timber Grades</h2>
        <?php echo $timber_grades; ?>
        <?php
    }
    if (!empty($profiles_available)) {
        ?>
        <h2>Profiles</h2>
        <?php echo $profiles_available; ?>
        <?php
    }
    if (!empty($specification)) {
        ?>
        <h2>Specification</h2>
        <?php echo $specification; ?>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php
}
?>
```

The issue can be seen on this page:

https://www.blueprintdoorsandfloors.co.uk/solid-oak-3-ledged-braced-cottage-door

When inspecting the code the issue can be seen as the image path not being generated correctly:

```
<img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" blueprint="" oak-ledged-doors="" made-to-measure-oak-ledged-doors.jpg"}}"="" alt="Made to Measure Oak ledged Doors">
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue, or one similar, and found a solution.

Any assistance or advice would be appreciated as this has been baffling me for a few days now on and off.

The site is running Magento 2.2.5 Community Edition

Thanks

Kev